# Как сделать, чтобы всплывающее окно появлялось при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, css

Сейчас только на первой, как сделать чтобы на второй тоже было, но при этом чтобы они открывались, независимо друг от друга

```js
animateDisplay = function(target, animationClass, displayType, timeout) {
    // timeout should be longer than css transition
    var doneTimedDisplay = false,
      displaying = false;

    target.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
      if (!target.classList.contains('show')) {
        target.style.display = 'none';
      }
      doneTimedDisplay = true;
    });
    if (!target.style.display || target.style.display === 'none') {
      displaying = true;
      target.style.display = displayType;
    } else {
      displaying = false;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      target.classList.toggle(animationClass);
      doneTimedDisplay = false;
    }, 10);

    if (!displaying) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        // failsafe for transitioned not firing
        if (!doneTimedDisplay) {
          target.style.display = 'none';
        }
        doneTimedDisplay = true;
      }, timeout);
    }
  };

 document.querySelector('.mybutt')
   .addEventListener('click', function() {
   animateDisplay(document.querySelector('.content'), 'show', 'block', 300)
 });
```

```css
.box {

}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  left: 30px;
}

.content.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mybutt {



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CodePen - display none transition</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<button class="mybutt">Hit me 1</button>
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">Hi 1</div>
</div>


<button class="mybutt">Hit me 2</button>
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">Hi 2</div>
</div>


<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы устаналиваете слушатель только на первый элемент. Для того, чтобы на все элементы с определенным классом повесить, Вам надо использовать querySelectorAll и forEach

Comment: я незнаю как это написать, я сидел с этим неделю, но неполучилось ничего, пробовал разные варианты

Comment: там должен быть, список постов, и под каждым постом кнопка поделиться всплывающая это на вордпресе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как сделать чтобы на второй тоже было, но при этом чтобы они открывались, независимо друг от друга

Предлагаю для удобства немного изменить `html` (см.пример ниже). Это позволит довольно просто определять группу элементов через единого родителя.

Поскольку поиск "соседних" элементов более мудреный. :)

```js
const ob = document.querySelector('body')
ob.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const o = e.target.closest('.mybutt')
  if (!o) {
    if (e.target.closest('.content')) return
    ob.querySelectorAll('.content.show').forEach(el => animateDisplay(el, 'show', 'block', 300))
    return
  }
  const op = e.target.closest('.container')
  const el = op.querySelector('.content')
  animateDisplay(el, 'show', 'block', 300)
});

function animateDisplay(target, animationClass, displayType, timeout) {
  // timeout should be longer than css transition
  var doneTimedDisplay = false,
    displaying = false;

  target.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    if (!target.classList.contains('show')) {
      target.style.display = 'none';
    }
    doneTimedDisplay = true;
  });
  if (!target.style.display || target.style.display === 'none') {
    displaying = true;
    target.style.display = displayType;
  } else {
    displaying = false;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    target.classList.toggle(animationClass);
    doneTimedDisplay = false;
  }, 10);

  if (!displaying) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // failsafe for transitioned not firing
      if (!doneTimedDisplay) {
        target.style.display = 'none';
      }
      doneTimedDisplay = true;
    }, timeout);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box {}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  left: 30px;
}

.content.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mybutt {}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button class="mybutt">Hit me 1</button>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">Hi 1</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class='container'>
  <button class="mybutt">Hit me 2</button>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">Hi 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: круто, спасибо !

Comment: это, конечно, отлично. Но человек так не разберется с коллекцией элементов и методами их обработки

Comment: я просто незнаю сколько бы ещё просидел, неделю, две

Comment: @PavelNazarian, тебе видней с чем нужно разбираться человеку...

Comment: @ksa к чему этот обиженный фамильярный негатив? я не давал повода. Мой комментарий был крайне нейтрален

Comment: @PavelNazarian, это все в твоей голове, не более того...

Comment: @ksa не дуйся, всё будет хорошо

Comment: @ksa в его голове? Ну ладно ладно...)

Comment: как можно сделать чтобы окно закрывалось, если мимо него кликнуть ?

Comment: @Anrisssss, я добавил закрытие, если кликнуть "мимо".

Comment: @ksa, спасибо, не пойму, почему если это убрать из боди width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;, то  плохо срабатывать начинает

Comment: @Anrisssss, если убрать "растяжение" `body` - он занимает место не на всю страницу, а только на ту ее часть, что занимает контент.

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.mybutt').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {      
      animateDisplay(this.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.content'), 'show', 'block', 300)
    });
 })
```